# Record computer sounds with PulseAudio and C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, pulseaudio

Is there a way to record all the sound that is played on a Linux Machine using PulseAudio? E.g. like Stereomix in Windows.

I dont want a complete Program, I just need some entry point to start my researches. Somehow I do not find very much regarding this topic.

So if anyone has informations on this topic (of course this can be tips, hints or maybe open source programs that do this), please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I researched this exact problem yesterday, so I have some steps you can try. I was using Ubuntu 15.04.

- Install `pavucontrol`, and run it.
- Go to the "Recording" tab.
- Run a command like this in a shell, `arecord -f cd | hexdump  -Cv | grep '0000 '`, and you should see a new entry appear in the pavucontrol recording tab. You might see non-zero data if your microphone is enabled.
- Run YouTube or something in the background to generate sound.
- Click the drop-down item next to "ALSA Capture *from*" and switch 'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo' to 'Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo'. You should see non-zero data in the `arecord` session.

From there, its a matter of writing code to record audio using the ALSA api. You can use `arecord` as a reference.

The system (mine anyway) somehow remembers the "*from*" setting between invocations of `arecord`, even though the item in the Recording tab comes and goes.

Comment: Alternate approach: [Record a programs output with PulseAudio](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio)

Comment: I found this page myself. But I want to record all sound on the system, not just a single program. But thx!